# Get extra info within after(:each) in RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, rspec

I'm using RSpec and I want to get result (passed or not), class name, test name (or description) **and error message** (if present) of each test after once it finished.

So here is a pretty simple code

```
  describe MyClass do

    after :each do
      #how do I know a test passed, its name, class name and error message?
    end

    it "should be true" do 
        5.should be 5
    end

    it "should be false" do 
        5.should be 6
    end

   end
```

Your suggestions?

Comment: Doesn't RSpec tell you this when you run the `rspec` command?

Comment: I need to get that information within after(:each) callback exactly.

Comment: Why are you trying to do that? What's your bigger goal? That part of rspec isn't designed to look at anything related to which examples ran - just provide a place to clean up afterwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few formatters for test output that can show you which tests passed/failed/pending, and it sounds like you are interested in the one called `documentation`.

In order to make this formatter available for all your rspec files, create a file called `.rspec` with content:

```
--color  # I just like this one for more easily read output
--formatter documentation
```

This means that when you run a test suite like you have above you will see:

```
MyClass
  should be true
  should be false (Failed - 1)

  # Individual output for each error would show up down here
```

Reference: https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/2-11/docs/formatters/custom-formatters

Comment: Sorry, but I didn't say that I need " for test output ". I need to get that information within after(:each) callback exactly.

Comment: Hi, Alan. Thanks for the clarification. What are you doing with this information? I don't really understand what you're trying to do, but maybe that would help.

Answer (score 1):

You can get extra information from formatters, but since `after` hooks are potential points of failure, they don't expose failure information themselves.

See https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/2-11/docs/formatters/custom-formatters and https://github.com/rspec/rspec-core/blob/master/lib/rspec/core/formatters/base_formatter.rb

Comment: How can it help me? I don't need to see(!)  that at the terminal while rspec is running, I need to get that information within after(:each) callback exactly.